# Append row to Datatables?

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-ui, datatable, append

So I have a drag and drop functionality with my table information, and my issue is that the information appended to the Datatable is only there temporarily. So in this case, my Datatable shows 5 rows by default. When the appended rows are dropped, my pagination still shows 5 rows (even if there are 7 visible rows) after I've dropped 2 rows. By clicking page 2 on my pagination and clicking back to page 1, they are no longer there. I believe that .append() is not correct to use here, and rather .fnAddData() but I cannot get it working. I have the fiddle with the basic information here http://jsfiddle.net/YK5fg/1/ but I cannot emulate Datatables in jsfiddle unfortunately. Any ideas? Thanks in advance.

```
      $( ".drag" ).draggable({ revert: "invalid" });

      $( ".dropTarget" ).droppable({
        drop: function( event, ui ) {
          // fade out dropped icon      
          ui.draggable.hide();
          var dropped = parseInt($(this).attr('title')) + 1;
          $( this )
          .attr('title',dropped+' entries'); 

          var delay =  $(this);
              delay.prop('disabled', true).addClass('ui-state-highlight')
              setTimeout(function() {
                  delay.prop('disabled', false).removeClass('ui-state-highlight');
              }, 2000)

              var rowId = ui.draggable.prop("id");
              var cloned = $(".basic").find("tr#"+rowId).clone();
              $(".fav1").append(cloned);
              //.fnAddData(cloned);
        }
      });
```

Comment: i think you should add data to datatable. not only append row to the physical table

Comment: I'm not trying to add a row with new information, I am moving a current and already existing row.

Comment: I'd like to help but i can't understand what are you trying to achieve  or what's the problem that you are trying to solve.

Comment: Okay. I got a fiddle working. http://jsfiddle.net/YK5fg/3/ You can drag the arrow to the folder to move the row from home table to favorite table. It DOES NOT delete from the home table, for one. 2, if you double click the folder to view the favorite table, you can see the rows but the pagination/info won't update. I set the pagination to 2 for demo sake. Add 2 rows to the favorite table by drag/drop into folder and view favorite table by dbl click on folder . 3 rows are there, info is off. Click the pagination next, the prev and the rows are gone.

Comment: Better explained here. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18986968/rows-disappearing-on-datatables